# Changing span of an item in <nav> when scrolling down to an element with a specific id

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my HTML + Bootstrap webpage, there is a `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">`. In the navbar I have this:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

That `class="active"` is always there. But there is an another `<li>`:

```
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
```

If I click on the `<li>`, the page goes down to the element with the tag `action`:

```
<h1 style="text-align: center;" id="about">About</h1>
```

But after the scroll, the "Home" `<li>` is still active and the "About" `<li>` is still inactive.
How can I change which `<li>` is active?

Comment: Make it via Javascript....

Comment: @Put12co22mer2 K. If you know how to detect "scrolling to an element with a specific id" then please post it in an answer.

Comment: If you know the code you're working on, please share the js that makes it scroll when you click on the 'li'.

Comment: @Put12co22mer2 There is just a href="#about" on the button element.

Comment: @Put12co22mer2 It's my project and there's no JS in the WHOLE thing...

Answer (score 0):

In order to switch a class, you need to use some Javascript:

```
    var menu = document.querySelector('<put direct parent of lists here (ex: .menu)>');
    var anchors = menu.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i += 1) {
      anchors[i].addEventListener('click', function() { clickHandler(anchors[i]) }, false);
    }

    function clickHandler(anchor) {
      var hasClass = anchor.getAttribute('class');
      if (hasClass !== 'active') {
        anchor.setAttribute('class', 'active');
      }
    }
```

Hope this helps :)